# How to limit upload to images only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have built a website that is for image sharing.

a user upload an image (PNG or JPEG files)

I have checked the file type in my code so if it is non PNG or JPEG, it won't get uploaded.

but what happened is that I have found that there are many .php files got uploaded some how!!

and got my website hacked in the end :(

How can I protect my website but only allowing real image files to be uploaded only

I use ASP.net C#

Comment: `many .php files got uploaded` ?? in the same path of Images ???

Comment: @zey yes in the same path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here below code will work for you. Whatever the extensions that you accept by the system you can add to the accept

```
asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploader" runat="server" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" />
```

I think that this would be fine unless you are not going for a validation like this,

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuImportImage" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexValidator" runat="server"
 ControlToValidate="fuImportImage"
 ErrorMessage="Only JPEG images are allowed" 
 ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Jj][Pp][Gg])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg])$)">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict type using "accept" attribute. It will validate mime-type of the file.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadFileType" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" />
```

Unfortunately it's not ideal and you want some sort of back-end solution as well. Since you can still upload rootkit as a .jpg file,
maybe additionally checking file headers would be a good idea. Perfectly you would want a proper rootkit detecting solution before you accept file on the server.